# Multiple streams not writing correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, stream

I need help to fix a bug in the method below, it's a method to write a file from a readable stream to a store (eg: HDD, Cloud).

It is possible to apply some transformation to the file before writing (using a pipe in `self.transformWrite()`).

If copies are defined (in `copyTo`), then the same `write` method is called on each store, so one call to `write` could lead to a cascade of `write`.

The problem I am facing is maybe with streams, maybe with async I don't really know, I have one readable stream and possibly one or more writable streams (at least one for each `write` call).

Sometimes, the `from.on('end'` event is not called so the expecting code is never executed even if the file has been correctly and entirely written to disk... Or sometimes, the files are created with 0 bytes..

Here is the complete code :
https://github.com/jalik/jalik-ufs/blob/master/ufs-store.js

```
    /**
     * Writes the file to the store
     * @param rs
     * @param fileId
     * @param callback
     */
    self.write = function (rs, fileId, callback) {
        var file = self.getCollection().findOne(fileId);
        var ws = self.getWriteStream(fileId, file);
        var errorHandler = function (err) {
            self.getCollection().remove(fileId);
            self.onWriteError.call(self, err, fileId, file);
            callback.call(self, err);
        };

        rs.on('error', Meteor.bindEnvironment(errorHandler));
        ws.on('error', Meteor.bindEnvironment(errorHandler));
        ws.on('finish', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
            var size = 0;
            var from = self.getReadStream(fileId, file);

            from.on('data', function (data) {
                size += data.length;
            });
            from.on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
                // Set file attribute
                file.complete = true;
                file.progress = 1;
                file.size = size;
                file.token = UploadFS.generateToken();
                file.uploading = false;
                file.uploadedAt = new Date();
                file.url = self.getFileURL(fileId);

                // Sets the file URL when file transfer is complete,
                // this way, the image will loads entirely.
                self.getCollection().update(fileId, {
                    $set: {
                        complete: file.complete,
                        progress: file.progress,
                        size: file.size,
                        token: file.token,
                        uploading: file.uploading,
                        uploadedAt: file.uploadedAt,
                        url: file.url
                    }
                });

                // todo move copy code here

                // Return file info
                callback.call(self, null, file);

                // Execute callback
                if (typeof self.onFinishUpload == 'function') {
                    self.onFinishUpload.call(self, file);
                }
            }));
        }));

        // Simulate write speed
        if (UploadFS.config.simulateWriteDelay) {
            Meteor._sleepForMs(UploadFS.config.simulateWriteDelay);
        }

        // todo execute copy after original file saved
        // Copy file to other stores
        if (options.copyTo instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < options.copyTo.length; i += 1) {
                var copyStore = options.copyTo[i];
                var copyId = null;
                var copy = _.omit(file, '_id', 'url');
                copy.originalStore = self.getName();
                copy.originalId = fileId;

                try {
                    // Create the copy
                    copyId = copyStore.create(copy);

                    (function (copyStore, copyId, copy) {
                        // Write the copy
                        copyStore.write(rs, copyId, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err) {
                            if (err) {
                                copyStore.getCollection().remove(copyId);
                                self.onCopyError.call(self, err, copyId, copy);
                            }
                        }));
                    })(copyStore, copyId, copy);
                } catch (err) {
                    copyStore.getCollection().remove(copyId);
                    self.onCopyError.call(self, err, copyId, copy);
                }
            }
        }

        // Execute transformation
        self.transformWrite(rs, ws, fileId, file);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to make it simple, instead of using the same readable stream, I had to re-open the same stream for each copy, so here is the new code :

```
    self.write = function (rs, fileId, callback) {
        var file = self.getCollection().findOne(fileId);
        var ws = self.getWriteStream(fileId, file);

        var errorHandler = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err) {
            self.getCollection().remove(fileId);
            self.onWriteError.call(self, err, fileId, file);
            callback.call(self, err);
        });

        ws.on('error', errorHandler);
        ws.on('finish', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
            var size = 0;
            var from = self.getReadStream(fileId, file);

            from.on('data', function (data) {
                size += data.length;
            });
            from.on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
                // Set file attribute
                file.complete = true;
                file.progress = 1;
                file.size = size;
                file.token = UploadFS.generateToken();
                file.uploading = false;
                file.uploadedAt = new Date();
                file.url = self.getFileURL(fileId);

                // Sets the file URL when file transfer is complete,
                // this way, the image will loads entirely.
                self.getCollection().update(fileId, {
                    $set: {
                        complete: file.complete,
                        progress: file.progress,
                        size: file.size,
                        token: file.token,
                        uploading: file.uploading,
                        uploadedAt: file.uploadedAt,
                        url: file.url
                    }
                });

                // Return file info
                callback.call(self, null, file);

                // Execute callback
                if (typeof self.onFinishUpload == 'function') {
                    self.onFinishUpload.call(self, file);
                }

                // Simulate write speed
                if (UploadFS.config.simulateWriteDelay) {
                    Meteor._sleepForMs(UploadFS.config.simulateWriteDelay);
                }

                // Copy file to other stores
                if (options.copyTo instanceof Array) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < options.copyTo.length; i += 1) {
                        var copyStore = options.copyTo[i];
                        var copyId = null;
                        var copy = _.omit(file, '_id', 'url');
                        copy.originalStore = self.getName();
                        copy.originalId = fileId;

                        try {
                            // Create the copy in the collection
                            copyId = copyStore.create(copy);

                            (function (copyStore, copyId, copy) {
                                // Write the copy to the store
                                var cs = self.getReadStream(fileId, file);
                                copyStore.write(cs, copyId, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        copyStore.getCollection().remove(copyId);
                                        self.onCopyError.call(self, err, copyId, copy);
                                    }
                                }));
                            })(copyStore, copyId, copy);
                        } catch (err) {
                            copyStore.getCollection().remove(copyId);
                            self.onCopyError.call(self, err, copyId, copy);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }));
        }));

        // Execute transformation
        self.transformWrite(rs, ws, fileId, file);
    };
```